# no matching function for call to 'game_rule' in c++

Tags: c++, arrays, function, c++14, tic-tac-toe

I am writing a tic-tac-toe project in C++. I wrote the `game_rule` function to control the game flow and I called it in the game over function I got an error message "no matching function for call to 'game_rule'". I tried every possible way to figure out why but was unsuccessful. I passed the custom 2d array but it doesn't have any effect.

Full code can be seen on:

[code of tic-tac-toe](https://gist.github.com/ultimatedark/ec0be6248d9996f182f35ec117fb39d1)

```
bool game_rule()
{

    if ((board_ele[0][0] == 'X' && board_ele[1][1] == 'X' && board_ele[2][2] == 'X') || (board_ele[0][0] == 'X' && board_ele[0][1] == 'X' && board_ele[0][2] == 'X') || (board_ele[1][0] == 'X' && board_ele[1][1] == 'X' && board_ele[1][2] == 'X') || (board_ele[2][0] == 'X' && board_ele[2][1] == 'X' && board_ele[2][2] == 'X') || (board_ele[0][0] == 'X' && board_ele[1][0] == 'X' && board_ele[2][0] == 'X') || (board_ele[0][1] == 'X' && board_ele[1][1] == 'X' && board_ele[2][1] == 'X') || (board_ele[0][2] == 'X' && board_ele[1][2] == 'X' && board_ele[2][2] == 'X'))
    {
        return true;
    }
    else
    {
        return false;
    }
}

void game_over()
{

    if (game_rule(board_ele) == true)
    {
        std::cout << "player 1 is won";
    }

    if (game_rule(board_ele) == true)
    {
        std::cout << "player 1 is won";
    }
}
```

Comment: `game_rule` takes no arguments, but when you call it you are passing the board. Is this a typo?

Comment: `bool game_rule()` declares that the function takes no arguments. You might need to take a few steps back and go back to your text-books, tutorials or class-notes and read more about functions and how to declare/define them.

Comment: just remove  `board_ele` when you call the function `game_rule(board_ele)==true ` in line `112` and `117` to be `game_rule()==true ` https://onlinegdb.com/SyPRQqbor

Comment: thank you for help,now it's working very fine,i miss the argument,but now it's working very well.

Comment: (OT: `== true` is superfluous.)

Comment: In the same vein as Biffen’s comment: the pattern `if (condition) return true; else return false;` should **always** be written as `return condition`; — it’s shorter, clearer and more readable and, most importantly, it *just makes more sense*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are declaring `bool game_rule()` with no inputs however when you do call it here `if (game_rule(board_ele)==true)` you pass it inputs.

If you want to pass parameters to **game_rule** define it so it can receive an input from the same type as **board_ele**.